# GRUB 2 "The current input timing is not supported" on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: grub2, burg

I have monitor DELL u2412m, on my machine Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 8.1 are installed. BURG didn't work, I wanted to fix it, but with no luck, instead I messed that up and computer just rebooted again and again. I reinstalled grub 2 using Live CD, without burg, and now during boot I don't get BIOS load screen and after that grub menu, but all I can see is some info "The current input timing is not supported. Change your input timing to 1920x1200@60Hz...", so I used Grub customizer and set custom resolution to all available resolutions for my monitor I found on Windows listed and these are: 1920x1200, 1680x1050, 1280x800 and finally 1024x768, but with no luck. Now when I want to go to Linux, I have to wait for beep sound and after a second or two, I blindly navigate with arrow to Linux and type Enter(Windows is listed as first on the list, because of my family).

My /etc/default/grub looks like this:

```html
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0"
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET="true"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="10"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL="console"

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
GRUB_GFXMODE="1024x768"
#GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX="1600x900"

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="true"

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks,
Deveti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have read many blogs that says this problem is specific for the DELL laptops , so the below might help you to get out the problem.
Have you tried this steps :

1. Hold the power button for 8+ seconds to reboot the pc.
2. Tap F8 key, until you see boot diagnostics menu
3. You will find **Enable VGA mode** , please select.

Comment: I restarted computer and just pressed F8 and get BIOS loading screen and GRUB menu. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am glad i could help you :)